# How should be information about logged in user passed to repository in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, repository

What is the best way of passing user information if items in database are assigned to specific users and no user can get access to data which isn't his? I have two ideas, but I don't know if any of them is correct.

First idea I don't like, because it requires to pass user name every time I want to get any data from repository:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(string userName)
    {
        return dbContext.Items.Where(i => i.UserName == userName);
    }
}
```

Second is injecting user name and it looks more natural to me, because I can use repository like there was no user authentication, but I have no idea if it's safe and if it's ASP.NET MVC style:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();
    private string userName;

    public Repository(string userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> Items
    {
        get { return dbContext.Items.Where(i => i.UserName == userName); }
    }
}

// In NinjectDependencyResolver.cs:

public void AddBindings()
{
    kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>().WithConstructorArgument(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
}
```

I don't know if it's good to use HttpContext class somewhere else than controller or view.

These are very simple examples and I didn't compile them, but I hope there's no mistakes and you know what I mean. Of course UserName should be part of another table with users, but I made it as simple as I could.

Comment: Your first example is the more natural way to get a users information out of the database. You would normally pass the username/userId from the controller to a service then onto the repository to be returned. This adheres to the separation of concerns, each class object doing one thing well and also decouples each class object from the next. Your second example to me looks unnatural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ItemsController : Controller {
    private readonly IItemsService _service;
    public ItemsController(IItemsService service) {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(){
        return View("Index", _service.GetItemsForUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name));
    }
```

}

your service would look like this

```
public class ItemsService : IItemsService {

    private readonly IItemsRepository _repository;

    public ItemsService(IItemsRepository repository) {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItemsForUser(string username) {
        return _repository.GetItems(username);
    }
}
```

and you repo

```
public ItemsRepository : IItemsRepository, IRepository {

    private DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();

    public ItemsRepository() {

    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(string username) {
        return _context.Items.Where(i => i.username == username).ToList();
    }
}
```

or something similar to this structure. I have used interfaces because I assume the use of inversion of control.

Comment: Is service necessary? There would be as many services as entities? Isn't it too complicated? Thank you for your answer, I would like to see someone else's opinion as well.

Comment: Not really, the example I have given is a very basic one so in this case it does look like overkill. The idea is to keep as much decoupling as possible. The services is where all the business logic goes. The repository is where the data access goes and the controller only controls the flow of that data to the view.

Comment: If you use the controller to access the repository directly you will end up with a bloated controller doing more than is required or a bloated repository doing more than is required. If you are required to use some functionality else where in your code base you will either have to replicate it or inject your repository which will get messy and cause dependencies which are not needed. The service is a way to mitigate this.